# Polls seeing multiple users as one user (D6)

Tags: 6, polls

For the polls core module, I am coming across an issue where if multiple users of the same role type try to vote, only the first person who did so can. It is almost as if it thinks that all the users of the same role are the same user.

Has anyone seen this, or know of a way to get around it?

Thanks.